LWC: maintain focus on radio group option after re-render
my LWC radio group component's input[type=radio] elements are losing focus when keyboard navigated to or clicked.
        <fieldset role="radiogroup" part="input-radio-group">
            ...
            <span class="slds-radio">
                <input type="radio"
                id="asc"
                disabled={rule.disableInputs}
                name={groupName}
                value="asc"
                checked={isAscendingChecked}
                onchange={handleOrderChange}/>
                <label class="slds-radio__label" for="asc">
                    ...
                </label>
            </span>
            <span class="slds-radio">
                <input type="radio"
                id="desc"
                disabled={rule.disableInputs}
                name={groupName}
                value="desc"
                checked={isDescendingChecked}
                onchange={handleOrderChange}/>
                <label class="slds-radio__label" for="desc">
                    ...
                </label>
            </span>
        </fieldset>

The input element's onchange handler handleChange, dispatches a CustomEvent:
handleChange(event) {
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('selection', {
            detail: {
                index: this.index,
                data: event.target.value,
            },
        })
    );
}

This CustomEvent is caught by the parent component of my LWC radio group:
       <template>
            ...
            <my-radio-group
                onselection={makeRadioRerender}>
            </my-radio-group>
            ...
       </template> 

And then a method makeRadioRerender is called which makes my radio-group rerender. So focus is lost on the input. How would I maintain focus even through these rerenders?

Showing actual code would be helpful here. You can [edit] your question to include code that exhibits this behavior. This will allow us to give you a more detailed, targeted answer.

@sfdcfox edited it.
